# how get to disable fieldspermissions fields for selectobject based on permissionset

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

like in permission set an account object have 28 fields when i query the fields permissions for select object it comes only the permission fields but i want all 28 fields

it means i want get all permission fields and without permission fields

how to do aim not getting  any resource for how to get the without permission fields how get to disable fields permissions fields  for select object based on permission set

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  This question is hard to understand and could benefit from [edit] with examples of what you are trying to do and what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [describeSObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm) call. The link points to the SOAP API, but you can also get this information in the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm), the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_object_info.htm), and the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_describe.htm). Permission sets do not include fields that cannot have their permissions changed. This is because it would cause errors during deployment, because those settings cannot be changed.